# If $x$ is a density point of $E$ , then dist$(x,E)=0$ for dist$(x,E)=$inf$\{|x-e|:e\in E\}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am learning measure theory, and here is a question I would like to ask.

Definition 1. Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set and $x \in E$. The point $x$ is called a density point if
$$
\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{m(E \cap[x-h, x+h])}{m([x-h, x+h])}=1 \, . 
$$

Definition 2. $\operatorname{dist}(x,E)=\inf\{|x-e|:e\in E\}$

Is it true that every density point of $E$ has $\operatorname{dist}(x,E)=0$?

I think this should be true because, if $\operatorname{dist}(x,E)\neq0$, then $\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} {m(E \cap[x-h, x+h])}=0$,and so the limit above will be $0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: If numerator and denomintor tend to $0$ you cannot say tht same thing about the ratio.

Comment: Your general idea is true. We just need to be more rigoros. Assume $d=\mathrm{dist}(x, E)>0$, then $\dfrac{d}{2}<|x-e|$, $\forall e\in E$, i.e. $E\cap [x-\dfrac{d}{2}, x+\dfrac{d}{2}]=\emptyset$. Then $\frac{m(E \cap[x-h, x+h])}{m([x-h, x+h])}=0$, $\ \forall \ 0<h<\dfrac{d}{2}\implies \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{m(E \cap[x-h, x+h])}{m([x-h, x+h])}=0$

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{dist}(x,E)>0\implies \exists R>0~\text{s.t}~E\cap \mathbb B(x,r)=\varnothing ~\forall r\leq R$. What does this say about the limit?

Comment: @K.defaoite will that mean limit goes to zero? Since $r$ will be eventually smaller than $R$ and at that time the numerator will become zero.

Comment: @RuiTang Exactly.